# MYSQL COUNT query trouble

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables which I will simplify below to illustrate my problem.

1) modules Table

```
| moduleId | moduleName | courseId |
```

2) videos table

```
 | videoId | videoName | duration | moduleId |
```

2) notes table

```
 | noteId | userId | videoId |
```

I have written a query to get the following information:

For every note in the notes table, get the moduleName and videoName it belongs to

```
SELECT module.moduleName, videos.videoName 
FROM videos,module,notes 
WHERE notes.userId = '$userId' 
  AND notes.videoId = videos.videoId 
GROUP BY videos.videoId
```

But my problem is that I want to count for each video, how many notes belong to it (have the given videos.videoId in the notes.videoId field)

Would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join to get the count for each video how many notes belong to it just join notes table with the common videoId and do group by with the videoId

```
SELECT v.*,m.moduleName,
COUNT(n.videoId )
FROM videos v
LEFT JOIN notes n USING(videoId)
LEFT JOIN modules m ON(v.moduleId =m.moduleId )
GROUP BY v.videoId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.moduleName, v.videoName 
FROM notes as n
LEFT JOIN videos as v on v.videoId=n.videoId
LEFT JOIN module as m on m.moduleId=v.moduleId
WHERE n.userId = '$userId' 
GROUP BY v.videoId
```